# How to replace a CSS class by another one when i change the media

Tags: class, css, overriding

I'm new in the usage of CSS, and i'm still in the learning curve

Basically, i want to display a section using the class col-xs-12 when i select the media `print` instead of a col-xs-9 in all other medias.

Is there an easy way in CSS to do that ?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve a similar effect, albeit changing the class name is not one of them.  
But you'll have to be a bit more specific about what it is that you're trying to do -- 

Why not just use @media print and re-define your css for .col-xs-9 ?

Comment: Do you really want to change the classname or do you just want to display other styles? You can't change HTML with CSS, just the appeareance of an element.

Comment: @rm-vanda: Well, how do i redefine my CSS to use col-xs-12 instead of col-xs-9 via a special CSS file for print? That was my question.

Comment: so col-xs-12 and col-xs-9 already have predefined rules?

Comment: Yes, they are classes related to the grid system offered by twitter bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

Using Bootstraps built-in classes you can either use jQuery, plain javascript or @media queries. If you're using Less or something you can use mixins. Since you mentioned you're new to CSS I'm going to assume it's plain old CSS.

You mentioned that you want col-xs-12 and col-xs-9. You can chain sizes together as well. Eg. `class="col-xs-12 col-lg-9"`, etc..

As noted in the .visible-print and .hidden-print classes you can have the following...

```
<div id="sectionContainer">
    <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-print">
        <!-- Add the content to see if your viewing on a web page -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 visible-print">
        <!-- Content to show in print -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change classes in CSS -

A viable workaround that does not involve JavaScript would be to make a third class `print` and copy+paste the css rules from col-xs-12 to it -- 
Add this new class to everything that is col-xs-9 which you want to be displayed as col-xs-12 on `media print`, 
and finally, to keep things smooth, put whatever styles you need and your new `.print` styles  into a separate .css file and link it in the head:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">`

(or, if it isn't a gigantic file at that point, `@media only print{}` is acceptable )

Alternatively, if you won't be using the col-9 class, you can just swap their classnames in your @media section.

Or, if you're comfortable with a javascript solution, you could add a "Print" button to your page that would do something like

```
$("#printButton").click(function(){ 
     $(".col-xs-9").addClass("col-xs-12").removeClass("col-xs-9");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A media query can only change what the selectors' rules are from size to size, it can't change the selectors you've put into the markup. To change the class in the markup would require the use of Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

YOu oould restyle you col-xs-12 specifically for print to match that of col-xs-12 , or similarly, add a new class, col-xs-12-print and style it to match col-xs-9

Comment: Is there a way to redefine the class without having to rewrite all the bootstrap styles ? Something like calling a class inside another class.

Answer (score 0):

when using twitter bootstrap they have classes to hide and show certain elements for print

```
.visible-print and .hidden-print
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-print